# Why is Tomcat unable to show the actual stack trace?

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat

Using `GWT`, I have deployed my server into **Tomcat**. This works fine, but when `GWT` throws an exception, a Popup shows the client the stack trace of the exception.

In dev mode, this works fine. In Tomcat, I get the below stack trace.

**Why and how do you fix this?**

> ```
> Unknown.Le(StackTraceCreator.java:168)
> Unknown.Jd(StackTraceCreator.java:421)
> Unknown.NT(Exception_FieldSerializer.java:16)
> Unknown.g1(SerializerBase.java:55)
> Unknown.b1(SerializerBase.java:112)
> Unknown.D$(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
> Unknown.uAc(CustomException_FieldSerializer.java:39)
> Unknown.uBc(ServerSideException_FieldSerializer.java:12)
> Unknown.f1(SerializerBase.java:46)
> Unknown._0(SerializerBase.java:92)
> Unknown.D$(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
> Unknown.B_(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:216)
> Unknown._o(Request.java:287)
> ```

**After using @Christian Kuetbach's answer, here is what I get now:**

> Unknown.com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_StackTraceCreator$CollectorEmulated_$fillInStackTrace__Lcom_google_gwt_core_client_impl_StackTraceCreator$CollectorEmulated_2Ljava_lang_Throwable_2V(StackTraceCreator.java:168)
>   Unknown.java_lang_Throwable_Throwable__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_Throwable_2V(StackTraceCreator.java:421)
>   Unknown.com_google_gwt_user_client_rpc_StatusCodeException_StatusCodeException__ILjava_lang_String_2V(StatusCodeException.java:35)
>   Unknown.com_google_gwt_user_client_rpc_impl_RequestCallbackAdapter_$onResponseReceived__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_rpc_impl_RequestCallbackAdapter_2Lcom_google_gwt_http_client_Request_2Lcom_google_gwt_http_client_Response_2V(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:209)
>   Unknown.com_google_gwt_http_client_Request_$fireOnResponseReceived__Lcom_google_gwt_http_client_Request_2Lcom_google_gwt_http_client_RequestCallback_2V(Request.java:287)
>   Unknown.com_google_gwt_http_client_RequestBuilder$1_onReadyStateChange__Lcom_google_gwt_xhr_client_XMLHttpRequest_2V(RequestBuilder.java:395) Unknown.anonymous(XMLHttpRequest.java:287)

**Please Help!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to find all the information in the GWT docs, which you need to setup de-obfuscated logging, so here's the short version:

In your module file (.gwt.xml), add:

```xml
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated" />
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers" 
     value="true" />
```

On the client side, use something like

```java
import java.util.logging.Logger;

private static Logger rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");
...
rootLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "My message", e);
```

You don't have to create a `RemoteLoggingServiceAsync` instance on the client side - it's used automatically by the logger, because we specified `<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED" />`.

On the server side, configure the RemoteLoggingServiceImpl. You will have to tell it, where it finds the symbolMaps, which will be generated when compiling with the GWT compiler argument `-extra /path/to/myExtraDir`. I personally use the approach to override RemoteLoggingServiceImpl, to allow specifying the directory from web.xml's `<init-param>`s <sup>[*]</sup>

```java
package mypackage.server;

public class ConfigurableRemoteLoggingServiceImpl extends RemoteLoggingServiceImpl {

  @Override
  public void init(final ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);

    final String symbolMapsDirectory = 
        config.getInitParameter("symbolMapsDirectory");
    setSymbolMapsDirectory(symbolMapsDirectory);
  }
}
```

In `web.xml`, register it like

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>remoteLogging</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.server.ConfigurableRemoteLoggingServiceImpl</servlet-class>

  <init-param>
    <param-name>symbolMapsDirectory</param-name>
    <param-value>/path/to/myExtraDir/mymodulename/symbolMaps</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>remoteLogging</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mymodulename/remote_logging</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Replace `/path/to/myExtraDir`, `mymodulename` and `mypackage` with your own values, and don't forget to call the GWT compiler with the [`-extra` argument](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#DevGuideCompilerOptions) (Note that you you don't have to use `-style PRETTY` or DETAILED, it also works with OBF). Keep all generated symbolMaps: Without them, deobfuscation will not work. As every new version gets a unique name automatically, you can collect them all in a safe central place when building.

<sup>[*] And I really, really wonder, why RemoteLoggingServiceImpl doesn't implement that itself!</sup>

Comment: _/path/to/myExtraDir_ how should it be written? Relative path, absolute path or something else?

Comment: The path is evaluated as a simple `new File("/path/to/myExtraDir")`, see `StackTraceDeobfuscator.setSymbolMapsDirectory(String symbolMapsDirectory)`, so you can use anything that works with the usual `java.io.File(String)` constructor (e.g. if it starts with a forward slash on Unix, it's an absolute path, ...).

Answer (score 5):

> Why?

As Christian Kuetbach said, this is the difference between running in DevMode (where your code executes in Java) and prod mode (where your code has been compiled to JavaScript and optimized, which includes renaming classes and methods).

> How do you fix this?

You don't. Generally speaking, showing stack traces to your users is not a good idea. Much better is to log the exception by sending it to the server (e.g. use `java.util.logging` to log, along with the `SimpleRemoteLogHandler` to send the log to the server, where it'll be logged using `java.util.logging`).

There are ways to deobfuscate the stack trace though, and the `RemoteLoggingServiceImpl` servlet can be configured to do it automatically.
See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WebModeExceptions for the gory details.

If you can't or don't want to use remote logging, then you can "manually" deobfuscate the stack trace: look at the file in `WEB-INF/deploy` (default location, can be changed by passing `-deploy` to the GWT compiler) corresponding with the permutation (same name as the `*.cache.*` file loaded by the browser), it'll tell you which Java method the `Le` method originates from.
But you already have the source file name and line number, so you don't really need it, right?

Comment: Sometimes exceptions can be caused by a clumsy client mistake. So, I don't want to log every exception, I want to give the client the opportunity to decide if he wants to sned it, save it or do nothing with it

Comment: StackTraceCreator is not actually the source file name, neither is the line number

Comment: @Adel: "Clumsy" client mistakes should ideally result in clean validation messages. Everything else is not really a client mistake, but rather a bug in the software - which should get fixed. In that case, you could display an opaque message like "An error has occurred. Do you want to send an error report?"

Comment: @ChrisLercher _"An error has occurred. Do you want to send an error report?"_ It is what I already do. The problem is that the error sent contains the incomprehensible stack trace above which makes the sending useless as the developer will not understand the log.

Comment: @Adel: You can de-obfuscate it on the server side by following Thomas's advice.

Comment: @ChrisLercher Man did you see my edited question? I already did everything possible and this is the best result so far

Comment: @Adel: Yes I saw it. You should try [RemoteLoggingServiceImpl](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/logging/server/RemoteLoggingServiceImpl.java). It produces near-perfect stack traces , if [set up correctly](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WebModeExceptions#Emulated_Stack_Data) (they don't look like the one you posted in your edited question).

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected, because the optimaziation will remove the method and class names.

You can compile as PRETTY or DETAILED, to get better readable Stacktraces.

There is also the posibility to emulate Stacktraces.

```
<set-property name="compiler.emulatedStack" value="true"/> 
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers" value="true"/>
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordFileNames" value="true"/>
```

This is a bad idea for production use, because it will increase the size of your javascript.

**update:**
I see a Exception_FieldSerializer Exception.

Do you try to serialize something, which is not serializable?

Classes, without a default constructor are not serializable, Classes which aren't within your client or shared package. If you try to serialize an Exception this can be the problem.

Comment: Method names and class names ?

Comment: See my edit please. I have tried both pretty and Detailed with the mentioned properties and now I get new stack trace

Comment: all classes extending exception are serializable and all i send are serializable exceptions

Comment: Sure, but there are the shared / client / server packages in a GWT project. I am not sure, if classes from outside the client oder share package will be serialized, even if they would be serializable.

Comment: Actually my exception class (CustomException) lies in the shared package