# Is there a way to deobfuscate already obfuscated GWT javascript code, that was obfuscated by me?

Tags: gwt, obfuscation

I want to have a possibility to decode error stacktraces that appear in the production environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Tomcat unable to show the actual stack trace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688587/why-is-tomcat-unable-to-show-the-actual-stack-trace)

Comment: Remote logging is certainly exactly what I need. Only one little drawback to it can be that my app can be a chrome extension that can run offline. Also remote logging can be a bit against no-tracking policy and some users might not like it. Thanks

Comment: I believe that stack traces (in contrast to error messages which are designed for the user) aren't very useful until users _send_ them to you. For that, they'll probably have to go online. They could send the trace from a Dialog, or they could even paste it into an email - all you need is the (obfuscated) stack trace + the permutation strong name. Then you can re-symbolize it on the server (just dig a bit through the code of RemoteLoggingServiceImpl, and you should be able to write a little tool which can do this for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the JsEmulateStackTrace class. Its seemly very complex and have never really gotten around to implementing it fully myself.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WebModeExceptions

this hypothetically remaps your symbol map for you, but honestly i doubt it works fully as i haven't seen a library/module yet that provides proper stack tracing for gwt. So that tells me its pretty hard or not fully working.

honestly it might be better to create some code to inject at compile time that provides stack trace support, that allows you to generate your own stack trace rather then using the actual java script stack trace. IE.. you might be able to create a single base class for all of your classes that you compile. With maybe an annotation or something. Then have your build script extend all of your classes pre compile so they are transparent to the dev, but included with the compiled cache file. You could have your base class grab the class name and or method name or something. and manage it with a simple stack that you can pop.

Comment: I think this gets me quite close, the document points me to [Resymbolization_/_Deobfuscation](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WebModeExceptions#Resymbolization_/_Deobfuscation). I think also about taking the stack-trace and passing it to gwt-logging to deobfuscate it (since I don't want to use remote logging). Great!

Comment: gwt-logging might also provide some automagic de/obfuscating too which might be worth looking at. Another approach might also be to include a   copy of your sources and query the class and lines from there, but honestly i think it would be easier to figure out the webmodeexceptions.

Answer (score 3):

If you kept your symbolMap around, yes; e.g. check out

http://code.google.com/p/speedtracer/wiki/ResymbolizationProtocol

(disclaimer: never tried it, myself)