# Displaying error details in GWT application?

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, smartgwt, gxt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Tomcat unable to show the actual stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688587/why-is-tomcat-unable-to-show-the-actual-stack-trace)

I am using GWT. I have below code to display client side exception details.

```
public void onModuleLoad() {  
    GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new   
      GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {  
      public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e) {  
        // my logic which will display error details  
    }
```

Every thing works fine in hosted mode. i get clear exception stack trace details in hosted mode as below:

```
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
com.sample.UserDetailsGrid$1.handleEvent(UserDetailsGrid.java:52)
com.sample.UserDetailsGrid$1.handleEvent(UserDetailsGrid.java:1)
com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.BaseObservable.callListener(BaseObservable.java:178)
com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.BaseObservable.fireEvent(BaseObservable.java:86)
com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Component.fireEvent(Component.java:456)
com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.Grid.onClick(Grid.java:813)
com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.Grid.onComponentEvent(Grid.java:496)
com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Component.onBrowserEvent(Component.java:884)
com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1308)
com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1264)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

But the problem is, once java files are compiled into javascript and deployed to tomcat i get same exception details as below which we cannot understand anything from the stack trace.:

```
Error: (TypeError): null has no properties stack: FLg([object Object],[object Object])@http://localhost:9999/mywebapp/21D01FA6800CA5B30FF5BE80916CCD06.cache.html:
Unknown.FLg(Unknown source:0)
Unknown.ILg(Unknown source:0)
Unknown._Xb(Unknown source:0)
Unknown.Rkc(Unknown source:0)
Unknown.bqd(Unknown source:0)
Unknown.wqd(Unknown source:0)
Unknown.ilc(Unknown source:0)
Unknown.tmc(Unknown source:0)
Unknown.I5f(Unknown source:0)
Unknown.anonymous(Unknown source:0)
Unknown.VNd(Unknown source:0)
```

Can you please explain me the reason for this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In dev mode, your code runs in Java. In prod mode, the compiled JavaScript is obfuscated.

See https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WebModeExceptions to learn about deobfuscating the stacktraces (on server-side)